# Integrating socket.io(^3.0.0) with Strapi Server("3.2.5") CORS Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, cors, strapi

I'm trying to build a simple chat app. I'm using create-react-app for the front-end, and I'm trying to integrate socket.io with Strapi server. My create-react-app server is running on Port 3000, while my Strapi local server is running on port 1337.

I've used this command to install starpi `yarn create strapi-app chat-app` and manually selected `mongodb` as database.

Receiving this error in the React app:

[image: react-socket-cors-err]

## Code

On my React component, I have this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:1337');

 const handleClick = () => {        
        const username = props.username;
        socket.emit("sendMessage", {
            chatMessage,
            username
        })
    }
```

In the Strapi backend, inside `./config/functions/bootstrap.js`

```
module.exports = async () => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        var io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server);

        strapi.io.on('connection', async function(socket) {

            socket.on('sendMessage', (msg) => {
                console.log("msg is", msg)
            })
            socket.on('disconnect', () =>{
                console.log('a user disconnected')
            });
        });
         strapi.io = io;
      })
};
```

I know to solve this `cors` error inside node app using cors module and use it like `app.use(cors())` But not sure how I resolve this in case of strapi?

I followed [this thread](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5869) and tried some of the workarounds, but none of them seem to work. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: can you add code of backend

Comment: My strapi backend code that I'm using is already above in the question. Do you need any specific code?

Comment: have you tried to use cors module `app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0");
    next();
});`

Comment: I'm aware of cors issue inside nodejs, know how to resolve it in Node. Not sure how do I achieve the same in Strapi CMS. 

I tried `require('socket.io')(strapi.server, { origins: "*" })` but this also doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3640 have you tried this or var http = `require('http').Server(app); const io = require('socket.io')(http, { origins: '*:*'});` and you are using socket 3.0.0 many things have been changed i this version check this changelog https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I did do something like this: 

```var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(strapi.server);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
.....
.....
```
Then I get 404 Not Found Error both in frontend(react) and strapi backend server

Answer (score 3):

So I resolved this issue by providing cors object to my socket.io. Option `origins` have been replaced with `cors` in the lastest version of socket.io(3.0.0)

```
    var io = require('socket.io')(strapi.server, {
            cors: {
              origin: "http://localhost:3000",
              methods: ["GET", "POST"],
              allowedHeaders: ["my-custom-header"],
              credentials: true
            }
   });
```

Checkout the socket migration guide for more info:

https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/

I'm able to receive messages in the backend now. Thanks, Arya!